# NSView failing to respond in a very simple program

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsview

New to Objective C, Project Builder and IB so please forgive my lack of knowledge...

I am attempting to create a simple program to learn and understand the use of the NSView class.  It consists of a single window with a single `NSView` and four buttons labeled, RED, GREEN, BLUE, and YELLOW.

The goal is to push a button and have the NSView fill with the appropriate color.  I have attempted several variations of the code but none seem to get any closer to a result.  Currently, upon execution, the window appears with a solid black square (my `NSView` subclass/object called MyView) and the four buttons.

I can successfully change the initial color of MyView within the MyView.h/.m files, however, I seem to be unable to change the color or redraw the MyView from my controller code (called AppController.h/.m).  I always receive a compiler warning.

The interface was created in IB and the Custom View object was pointed to the MyView subclass.  I've attached my code below.

```
//---------------------------
//
//  MyView.h
//

#import Cocoa/Cocoa.h

@interface MyView : NSView

int myColorChoice;

@end

//--------------------------
//
//  MyView.m
//

#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

int myColorChoice = 4;

-(void) setMyColorChoice : (int) c {

    myColorChoice = c;

}

-(void) drawRect: (NSRect) rect {

    switch (myColorChoice) {

        case 1 :
        [[NSColor greenColor] set];
        break;

        case 2 :
        [[NSColor blueColor] set];
        break;

        case 3 :
        [[NSColor redColor] set];
        break;

        case 4 :
        [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
        break;
    }

    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}

@end


//--------------------
//
//  AppController.h
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject {

    IBOutlet id display;
}

- (IBAction)makeBlue:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)makeGreen:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)makeRed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)makeYellow:(id)sender;

@end

//---------------------
//
//  AppController.m
//


#import "AppController.h"
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation AppController

- (IBAction)makeGreen:(id)sender {
    [MyView setMyColorChoice:1];
    [MyView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (IBAction)makeBlue:(id)sender {
    [MyView setMyColorChoice:2];
}

- (IBAction)makeRed:(id)sender {
    [MyView setMyColorChoice:3];
}

- (IBAction)makeYellow:(id)sender {
    [MyView setMyColorChoice:4];
}

@end
```

I'm fairly confident that i'm simply violating some basic principle, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one.  I suspect it must be something to do with MyView being improperly set up, as if I try to call any of my methods, the compiler gives me the "MyView may not respond to..." for any of the methods I've attempted to call.

NOTE:  I've only been modifying the makeGreen method for experimentation.  Once that works, I'll duplicate the code for the other colors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is setting up your `setMyColorChoice` method like this:

```
-(void)setMyColorChoice:(NSColor *)newColor
{
    [newColor set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Then you can clean up your `drawRect` method instead of using integers and a switch.  This would be the most efficient way since you don't need to declare instance variables thus saving memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to call instance methods on the `MyView` class. Your `AppController` needs a reference to an instance of that class. Probably the best way to do that is with an `IBOutlet` that you've hooked up in IB... if that's what your `display` ivar is, then all you need to do is call `[display setColorChoice:1]; [display setNeedsDisplay:YES];` etc.

Comment: Also, you haven't declared an instance variable `myColorChoice`, you've declared a file-scope variable.  Then, you've redeclared it in the implementation file.  In the interface, surround instance variable declarations with braces `@interface MyView { int myColorChoice; } ...`.  Don't (re)declare the variable in the implementation.  If you wish to initialize the instance variable to a certain value, do that in your init method.  (For a view created programmatically, that's initWithFrame:.  For one loaded from a NIB, that's -initWithCoder:.)  Or, you can do that in -awakeFromNib.

Comment: You are correct.  That is what I had set up display to be.  I just made that change and suddenly it works.. (not surprisingly).  What's strange is I swear I did that earlier but it didn't work.  I must have had multiple problems with this code and managed to fix some, while "unfixing" others.

Thank you for the explanation.  I have fixed those errors and everything is now working as I had expected it to work, and now have a better understanding of where I was making the mistakes.